# What is the advantages and disadvantages of having more reducers in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, reducers, bigdata

MapReduce programming is all about parallel processing, then why we start with single reducers in many cases. What is the advantages and disadvantages of having more reducers in MapReduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reducer might work on one or more partitions, thus it's limiting parallelization specifically by the fact that's it's only one.

Too many reducers will result in creating too many *small* HDFS (output) files, which is not good, and will put pressure on HDFS, because of the housekeeping needed to be done.

Comment: I guess you meant "thus it's limiting parallelization"... (instead of "not limiting")